# How would I implement a timer in a bank heist text based game whereby the more time their is on the clock, the more money that's stolen.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm giving myself a go at coding a text based adventure game that's centered around a bank heist. It's sort of a difficult story to represent as a text based game, but I digress.

What I want to add is a feature whereby the user has an in game time limit to complete the heist and the amount of time spent at the vault rewards the user's money balance at a constant or increasing increment. At the same time, the user isn't sitting at the screen waiting for that time limit to be over.

For example, the user starts out with 10 mins (in game) on the clock from starting the heist and by 5 minutes in, the user starts pulling money from the vault. From 5 minutes onwards the value of the money counter starts to increase at a constant or increasing increment (To cut down on time, the timer starts to fast forward, the user is simply able to skip the part and get the total tally or python automatically does the calculation and returns the balance to the user while making the necessary adjustment to the clock.). If the user starts to pull from 8 mins, they get more out of the vault, and so and so forth.

I don't know what features to include that would make it the time trial I intend it to be, but my main concern is how I would write out the code for an example like the one above. I have no idea how to write out code to represent this . I know it's a pretty weird question but any insight would help. (I apologize if this is the wrong place for the question).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the **time** library and build your application logic around it.

Your approach should go something like:

```
import time 

start_time = time.time()

while True: 

    time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time 

    if (time_elapsed > 5000):

        print("Hurry Up!")
```

Hope this helps you structure the program you want to build

Comment: Thank you. Gives me a better idea on where to start.